# Decimal keyword in array

Tags: arrays, django, decimal

To make a list in Django, I use this code:

```
myList.append([round(x/5),round(y/5,7)])
```

The result is:

```
[510, Decimal('0.0000516')]
```

But I need to:

```
[510, 0.0000516]
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What is x ? What is y ?

Comment: Actually x and y, can be each number. It's not important in this problem.

Comment: well trying it in ipython with x = 2550 and y = 1000 i got [[510.0, 200.0]] it's strange that you got only one array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of `0.0000516` in your final list is a float. You can easily convert a Decimal into a float using the built-in `float` function:

```
myList.append([float(round(x/5)), float(round(y/5,7))])
```